# Как растянуть div-блок на всю ширину страницы?

Tags: html, css

Проблема в том, что через комп див блок растягивается правильно, во всю ширину страницы, а через планшет или телефон див растягивается до границы экрана, а при прокрутке вправо или уменьшении масштаба там и остаётся. Скрин в самом низу с примером меньшенного масштаба. Блок отмечен красной стрелкой.

Что пробовал и не помогало:

```
body { width: 100%; height: 100%; }
.div { min-width: 100%; min-height: 100%; position: relative; }
```

[image]

Comment: А если вместо min-width - width: 100%;

Comment: Одинаково =(

Comment: что то явно мешает, надо смотреть код и стили.
Если нет, то можно попробовать так

   .div { position: absolute; width: 100% }

Только контент нужно будет отодвинуть на высоту этого блока вниз.

Comment: Абсолют не подходит. При полном экране всё нормально, как браузер уменьшаю, при прокрутке вправо блок остаётся на месте.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Так происходит, когда блоки сайта не помещаются в ширину экрана и остаются за его границами. Одно из следствий - появляется горизонтальный скролл. При этом те блоки, ширина которых была задана как `width: 100%` - остаются с такой шириной. В итоге вы скроллите вправо, и видите пустую область.

Решить это быстро можно вот так:

```
body {
  min-width: 1000px;
}
```

Этим вы зададите для страницы минимальную ширину, в которую все ваши блоки гарантированно впишутся. И даже если ширина экрана будет недостаточной для отображения всех блоков, и появится горизонтальный скролл - блоки с `width: 100%` будут отображаться во всю указанную ширину `1000px`.

Плюс, полезно бывает задать эту же величину в мета-теге в `head`:

```
<meta name="viewport" content='width=1000' />
```

Таким образом, заходя с мобильного, вы будете видеть всю страницу целиком, максимально "отзумленную".