# Div-блок съезжает при уменьшении окна браузера

Tags: html, css

Развёрнутое продолжение вопроса [Как растянуть div-блок на всю ширину страницы?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/360679) в картинках

Есть див блок. Красивый и чёрный с `width:100%`. Должен занимать всю ширину экрана.

**Смотрим через хром:**

[image]

Всё нормально.

**Уменьшаем окно браузера**

[image]

Вроде так же

**Мотаем вправо:**

[image]

Вот он косяк.

Значит, `width:100%` растягивает блок до границы экрана, а не страницы?

Что использовал:

```
html, body { width: 100%; height: 100%; }

.div { **min-width**: 100%;position: relative; }
```

и

```
html, body { width: 100%; height: 100%; }

.div { **width**: 100%;position: relative; }
```

Сломал голову. Прошу хелпа.

Comment: @Олег Б, в какой-то степени прав. Я сталкивался с такой же проблемой на twitter bootstrap 3.1 (уже не помню, как решил), проблема в css и скриптах левого меню, копать нужно в этом направлении.

Comment: Да, бутстрап, поставил в минхегхт минимальную ширину всех блоков, и всего делов.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас нижние блоки суммарно имеют ширину больше 100%, что в этом такого? Это очевидно, так как появился горизонтальный скролл. Задайте им ширину в процентах, ну или покажите html и стили, или дайте ссылку на эту страницу. Вот тут ( http://jsfiddle.net/nk3oyLao/ ) можно поиграться с min-width у стиля wrapper

Answer (score -1):

`max-width` ставь и будет тебе счастье)